# How do I get Popen to wait for git-bash.exe to be ready for keyboard input?

Tags: python, windows, bash, git

I work on the voice coding platform [Caster](https://github.com/dictation-toolbox/caster) and I am trying to automate checking out a pull request [here](https://github.com/dictation-toolbox/Caster/pull/498) using git-bash.exe on Windows.

The relevant part of the file [here](https://github.com/dictation-toolbox/Caster/blob/929d04d11fe9440f7b38563309878fbef9f138cc/castervoice/lib/github_automation.py#L54-L58) is:

```py
terminal = Popen(TERMINAL_PATH, cwd=local_directory)
# I'd like to replace this with a wait command
time.sleep(2)
Text(fetch_command).execute()
```

where `TERMINAL_PATH = <git-bash-dir>` and `Text(fetch_command).execute()` emulates keystrokes to put in a command fetching the pull request branch once the git bash window is ready.

Currently, it just waits 2 seconds hoping that the new window will be ready for input. How do I get python to wait until git-bash is ready for keyboard input?

Comment: Are you just interested in running a command or are you interested in actually spawning a terminal window? The former is easy, but I'm not sure if doing what you want in the latter case is possible.

Comment: Spawning the window is necessary in this case as the user has to actively press ENTER for the last step

Comment: I guess we could pop up a window to confirm the last step